# Discord.js: Detecting Message From Webhook

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a webhook bot. It sends webhook messages but it detects webhooks messages as same as normal messages. So it makes spam.

I use `discord.js` version 11.5.1

I thought this code will work but it did not work.

```js
if (message.author.nickname == null) return;
```

Comment: Maybe it's not null try this: if (!message.author.nickname) return;

Comment: I think `message.author.nickname` is not the true variable to test. I think there should be another variable for this case.

Comment: The code you gave cancels all commands

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for: [`Message#webhookId`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=webhookId)

```
if (message.webhookId) return;
```

(For Discord.js V12 and under, use `#webhookID` with `ID` all capitalised instead.)